# Como ordenar um array em PHP

Tags: php, html, array, ldap

Tenho o seguinte código que pega dados do servidor por meio do `ldap`, onde o `$info` me retorna um array ,estou tentando ordenar por ordem alfabética utilizando a função `sort` mas sem sucesso ,quando eu imprimo minha tabela ela continua fora de ordem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
...

```
$result_search = ldap_search($ds, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
 if ($result_search) {
   $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $result_search);
     $retorno = ldap_count_entries($ds, $result_search);
     $tabela = '<div id ="scrollbar">';
     $tabela .= '<table id="myTable">';
     $tabela .= '<thead>';
     $tabela .= '<tr>';
     $tabela .= '<th>Nome</th>'; 
     $tabela .= '<th>Telefone</th>';
     $tabela .= '</tr>';
     $tabela .= '</thead>';
     $tabela .= '<tbody>';
     foreach ($info as $key) {
         sort($info);
       if ( isset($key ['displayname'] [0] ) &&isset($key['telephonenumber'] [0]  )){
         $tabela .= '<tr>'; 
         $tabela .= '<td>'.$key ['displayname'] [0].'</td>'; 
         $tabela .= '<td>'.$key ['telephonenumber'] [0].'</td>';
         $tabela .= '</tr>';}
```

Esse e o meu retorno da variável `$info`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o `sort` é antes do `foreach` ! mas, também o código é com `usort`

Comment: Foi adequado agora com o exemplo do `array`.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda @NOVIC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php) nesse caso não é o recomendado, utilize o [usort](https://www.php.net/usort) que tem uma função para especificar qual elemento deseja fazer a ordenação no caso é o nome e com a função [strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcmp.php) que compara as `string`, exemplo:

```
usort($info, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['displayname'][0], $b['displayname'][0]); 
});
```

[Um exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/Oq0a4q)

Observação: esse evento é antes de mostrar as informações na tela, no seu caso antes do `foreach`, exemplo:

```
// primeiro ordena
usort($info, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['displayname'][0], $b['displayname'][0]); 
});
// depois mostra o resultado
foreach ($info as $key) {
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta,mas eu havia tentado isso e ele me traz a mensagem de erro ´Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\index.php on line 69´´que e exatamente o ponto da ordenação.

Comment: Eu vi a sua alteração da pergunta, que é o grande mau que não colocam toda a explicação e fiz a adequação @KALIBBAN

Comment: Sim ,funcionou!!Muito obrigado pela ajuda e desculpa não ter colocado o retorno logo de inicio.